# how to install nloptr on Linux

Tags: r

I have a box with antiX, which is a Debian clone. I compiled and installed nlopt and still:

```
> install.packages("nloptr")
Installing package into ‘/home/stephen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://utstat.toronto.edu/cran/src/contrib/nloptr_1.2.2.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2450931 bytes (2.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.3 MB

* installing *source* package ‘nloptr’ ...
** package ‘nloptr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for pkg-config... yes
configure: Now testing for NLopt header file.
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking nlopt.h usability... yes
checking nlopt.h presence... yes
checking for nlopt.h... yes
configure: Now testing for NLopt version 2.4.0 or greater.
configure: Suitable NLopt library found.
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
config.status: creating R/PkgFlags.R
** libs
g++  -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-3.5.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c dummy.cpp -o dummy.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-3.5.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c init_nloptr.c -o init_nloptr.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-3.5.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c nloptr.c -o nloptr.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-z,relro -o nloptr.so dummy.o init_nloptr.o nloptr.o -L/usr/local/lib -lnlopt -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/stephen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/nloptr/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘nloptr’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/stephen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/nloptr/libs/nloptr.so':
  libnlopt.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/stephen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/nloptr’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpEtHKlT/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("nloptr") :
  installation of package ‘nloptr’ had non-zero exit status
```

I went into the nloptr folder and ran ./configure and the compile statements that I see in the output and I have nloptr.so in the src folder. Is there a way to continue the install manually and copy what needs to be copied? or can I check that .so if it works?

```
$ ldd nloptr.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdb6dc1000)
    libnlopt.so.0 => not found
    libR.so => /lib/libR.so (0x00007f0e9e6b4000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f0e9e530000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f0e9e3ad000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f0e9e393000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0e9e1d2000)
    libblas.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblas.so.3 (0x00007f0e9e163000)
    libgfortran.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.5 (0x00007f0e9def5000)
    libquadmath.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007f0e9deb3000)
    libreadline.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.7 (0x00007f0e9dc66000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f0e9dbf2000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f0e9dbca000)
    libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007f0e9dbb5000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f0e9d997000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f0e9d98d000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0e9d988000)
    libicuuc.so.63 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.63 (0x00007f0e9d7b9000)
    libicui18n.so.63 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.63 (0x00007f0e9d4de000)
    libgomp.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f0e9d4ab000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0e9d48a000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0e9eb5b000)
    libtinfo.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6 (0x00007f0e9d45c000)
    libicudata.so.63 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.63 (0x00007f0e9ba6c000)

$ ls /usr/local/lib/libnl*
/usr/local/lib/libnlopt.so  /usr/local/lib/libnlopt.so.0  /usr/local/lib/libnlopt.so.0.10.0
```

Cheers

Stephen

Comment: The `configure` script find the nlopt header, library and suitable version. R then compiles and links find -- but fails when it tries to load the library.  That is very bizarre.  Can you do me a favour and run `ldd` on the `src/nloptr.so` file?  For me `libnlopt.so.0` is resolved fine.

Comment: I edited the question. Is there a way to copy files manually? I think sth is not copied where it is expected.

Comment: "Copy manually" sounds dangerous. You should really install `libnlopt-dev` from the distro (provided it is new enough?) as that ensures that its useable.  Currently, as the `ldd` out demonstrates there is disagreement between you and your computer.  You think you libnlopt, your computer tells you otherwise.  And that is the root of your problem.

Comment: @DE: pls post that as an answer and I will mark it as a solution. libnlopt-dev did it. I had installed nlopt from a tar.gz, I did not see anything about the dev version.

Comment: Done, added an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments above the issue here was a 'unconventional' (and hence not-working) 'installation' of the nlopt library: one cannot just untar it somewhere as the dynamic linker needs to know about it, update its cache etc.

So in short the recommended answer is to, where available as a suitable version, install the `-dev` package from the distro.  Here the command is

```
sudo apt install libnlopt-dev
```

after which `configure` in the R package sees, and also gets to use it as the corresponding shared library itself gets installed from the `libnlopt0` package.  (And we answered a few times why the `-dev` package is always needed for *building* as opposed to merely *running* via the shared library package).

Comment: the install of nlopt was done according to the install instruction in the package, configure, cmake and make install. the -dev package has stuff that is not found in the plain nlopt package. maybe the nloptr configure should be tweaked to check if -dev was installed?

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the documentation?  The difference could be as simple as you not knowing that `sudo ldconfig` is a required step (to update the cache of libraries the dynamic linker knows about) and something a package install (i.e. `apt` or `dpkg`) does for you.

Comment: And, if I may, we worked _a lot_ on the package installation. I am the author of the contributed code looking for a local library (which fell over for you as it ended up being half-installed only) whereas Jelmer is more conservative _and would have built the library for you as part of the installation of the R package_ had the local (yet borked) installation not been found.  So I don't want to sound difficult but it already is a very general process that simple fell over as a precondition was not met on your machine.

Comment: I appreciate the help. just describing what happened: first I tried to install by using install.packages; that failed; I googled and found advice to install nlopt manually by downloading the package; I did not try to install from apt. I read the instructions in the nlopt README and it installed; then nloptr started failing to load the library; I contacted the official maintainer of nloptr and he could not be bothered, so I tried Hans W and he told me to post here; then DE helped solve it.

Answer (score 1):

The previous solution did not worked on my machine (Ubuntu 18.04, R 4.2.0). In installed `nlopt` library from [github](https://github.com/stevengj/nlopt) using

```
git clone https://github.com/stevengj/nlopt.git
cd nlopt
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
```

Then `install.packages("nloptr")` worked with no issues